# How to model a user/group relationship where users are assigned an unique number within the group?

Tags: database-design

I am working on a web-server applications that deals with 2 entities:

- users
- groups

A user can belong to one, several or no group at all. Fairly usual, I assume.

However, I have additional constraints: each user should be able to receive a unique number (unique within the same group) in a "stable" and "deterministic" way, that is:

- If a user is added, removed or updated, the existing users must keep their actual assigned numbers in every group.
- The number should not be automatically assigned (not like an `id`. The number should be set explicitly by the web-server administrator when managing groups membership).

I haven't done a lot of *Data Modelling* and maybe this is dumb simple, by I can't decide which way to go and how to design my tables.

Do you guys have a suggestion ?

Comment: A user can be assigned with different numbers in different groups?

Comment: If a user is removed from a group, can his number be reused, reassigned to another user in the future?

Comment: If a user is removed from a group, and then joins it again, should the previous number be used again or a new number assigned to her?

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, a user can be assigned with different numbers in different groups. His number can eventually be reassigned and he may regain the same number if it is available and he rejoins the same group (but the admin may choose a different one for him).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your comments, I think you need a simple many-to-many table with an additional `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
TABLE UserGroups
  GroupID 
  UserID
  UserNumber
  PRIMARY KEY (GroupID, UserID)
  UNIQUE (GroupID, UserNumber)
  FOREIGN KEY (GroupID)
    REFERENCES Groups (GroupID)
  FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
    REFERENCES Users (UserID)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Any chance you know how to modelize such a relationship with  [`SQLAlchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) ? (But I guess this is rather a question for StackOverflow)

Comment: In case someone needed that in the future, [here the related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355499/how-to-model-a-unique-constraint-in-sqlalchemy) on stack-overflow.